# Simple Redirect to Rewritten URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a few PHP pages that I want to rewrite the URL for, and then redirect the original URL to the rewritten URL. An example below:

Old PHP URL: /this-page-is-useful.php

New URL: /useful/

I can get the the RewriteRule working using this code in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/useful/
RewriteRule ^useful/$ this-page-is-useful.php
```

So I can view /this-page-is-useful.php at /useful/ - which is what I want.

But now I want to redirect /this-page-is-useful.php to /useful/ through .htaccess

Anything I have tried to far has given me an internal error, or a redirect loop. This must be simple - but I just can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RedirectMatch as follow

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/this-page-is-useful\.php$ /useful/
```

Comment: This does redirect the page to /useful/ - but then I get redirect loop error

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer from a similar thread and just had to change it for my situation:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /this-page-is-useful\.php? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ useful/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^useful/(.*)$ /this-page-is-useful.php$1 [L,QSA]
```

I found the RewriteBase to be an important factor.